# Laravel 6 understanding route for pending post - not working

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6.2

I am learning Laravel and need to understand why the below once the route is working but the other one.

## Working

**URL:** `http://.../pending/post`

```
Route::get('pending/post', 'PostController@pending')->name('post.pending');
```

## Not Working

**URL:** `http://.../post/pending`

```
Route::get('post/pending', 'PostController@pending')->name('post.pending');
```

## Post Controller

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function pending()
    {
        return 'pending posts';
    }

    ...
}
```

> I want to use the `post/pending` which is not working.

Comment: both routes name are same that's why it is happening.

Comment: you mean if you swap the words, the route stops working??  any particular error??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon exactly, I am using either of them. Not both together. I want to use `post/pending` but that is not working. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: do you have any other route like `post/{something}`? and what error you are getting?? `404` or the generated url is different??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes using resource `Route::resource('post', 'PostController');`

Comment: that is why this is not working. the route matches with resource route's show.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I see, so what is the solution?

Comment: just change the orders of the routes. put your custom route above the resource route.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon oh that sounds simple yet confusing that the order matters.

Comment: yeah the order matters.